# Getting error in my android app

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, navigation-drawer

I am trying to develop a simple app with navigation drawer.
I do all my best and view so many articles but I failed
There is no error in my code but when I run my app in emulator it shows run time error...
plzz help me

here is my logcat file

```
12-19 15:07:20.562: E/AndroidRuntime(1067):     FATAL EXCEPTION: main

12-19 15:07:20.562: E/AndroidRuntime(1067):     java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.dhruv.sms/com.dhruv.sms.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException

12-19 15:07:20.562: E/AndroidRuntime(1067):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2180)

12-19 15:07:20.562: E/AndroidRuntime(1067):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)

12-19 15:07:20.562: E/AndroidRuntime(1067):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)

12-19 15:07:20.562: E/AndroidRuntime(1067):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)

12-19 15:07:20.562: E/AndroidRuntime(1067):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)

12-19 15:07:20.562: E/AndroidRuntime(1067):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)

12-19 15:07:20.562: E/AndroidRuntime(1067):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5039)

12-19 15:07:20.562: E/AndroidRuntime(1067):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)

12-19 15:07:20.562: E/AndroidRuntime(1067):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)

12-19 15:07:20.562: E/AndroidRuntime(1067):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
12-19 15:07:20.562: E/AndroidRuntime(1067):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main
(ZygoteInit.java:560)
12-19 15:07:20.562: E/AndroidRuntime(1067):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

12-19 15:07:20.562: E/AndroidRuntime(1067): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException

12-19 15:07:20.562: E/AndroidRuntime(1067):     at com.dhruv.sms.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:80)

12-19 15:07:20.562: E/AndroidRuntime(1067):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)

12-19 15:07:20.562: E/AndroidRuntime(1067):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)

12-19 15:07:20.562: E/AndroidRuntime(1067):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)

12-19 15:07:20.562: E/AndroidRuntime(1067):     ... 11 more
```

And this is my java file

```android
package com.dhruv.sms;



import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.app.FragmentManager;
import android.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    // Within which the entire activity is enclosed
    private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;

    // ListView represents Navigation Drawer
    private ListView mDrawerList;

    // ActionBarDrawerToggle indicates the presence of Navigation Drawer in the action bar
    private ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;

    // Title of the action bar
    private String mTitle = "";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

            mTitle = "App title";
            getActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);

            // Getting reference to the DrawerLayout
            mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);

            mDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.conversation_list);

            // Getting reference to the ActionBarDrawerToggle
            mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout,
                            R.drawable.ic_launcher, R.string.drawer_open,
                            R.string.drawer_close) {

                    /** Called when drawer is closed */
                    public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
                            getActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
                            invalidateOptionsMenu();

                    }

                    /** Called when a drawer is opened */
                    public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
                            getActionBar().setTitle("App title");
                            invalidateOptionsMenu();
                    }

            };

            // Setting DrawerToggle on DrawerLayout
            mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);

            // Creating an ArrayAdapter to add items to the listview mDrawerList
            ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getBaseContext(), 
                            R.layout.drawer_list_item, getResources().getStringArray(R.array.sidebar_list_array));

            // Setting the adapter on mDrawerList
            mDrawerList.setAdapter(adapter);

            // Enabling Home button
            getActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);

            // Enabling Up navigation
            getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

            // Setting item click listener for the listview mDrawerList
            mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                    int position, long id) {

                            // Getting an array of rivers
                            String[] menuItems = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.sidebar_list_array);

                            // Currently selected river
                            mTitle = menuItems[position];

                            // Creating a fragment object
                            Fragment rFragment = new Fragment();

                            // Passing selected item information to fragment


                            // Getting reference to the FragmentManager
                            FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();

                            // Creating a fragment transaction
                            FragmentTransaction ft = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();

                            // Adding a fragment to the fragment transaction
                            ft.replace(R.id.content_frame, rFragment);

                            // Committing the transaction
                            ft.commit();

                            // Closing the drawer
                            mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);

                    }
            });
    }



    @Override
    protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
            mDrawerToggle.syncState();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
            if (mDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
                    return true;
            }
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    /** Called whenever we call invalidateOptionsMenu() */
    @Override
    public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
            // If the drawer is open, hide action items related to the content view
            boolean drawerOpen = mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(mDrawerList);

            menu.findItem(R.id.action_settings).setVisible(!drawerOpen);
            return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
            getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
            return true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The variable `mDrawerList` might not be initialised correctly. It could be `null`, thus causing the `NullPointerException`.

Answer (score 0):

There is an error in your code. The stack trace shows that. And here's the relevant information

```
12-19 15:07:20.562: E/AndroidRuntime(1067): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException

12-19 15:07:20.562: E/AndroidRuntime(1067):     at com.dhruv.sms.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:80)
```

Line 80 shows mDrawerList being accessed. It's null

Answer (score 0):

the error is in this part of your code

```
mDrawerList.setAdapter(adapter);
```

mDrawerList reference might be wrong or adapter is wrong

Answer (score 0):

```
  private ListView mDrawerList=new ListView();
```

You haven't initialized the ListView.